# Nissan-appropriate jahrzeit observances

Tags: yahrtzeit, nissan

The jahrzeits of both of my grandfathers zq"l fall during Nissan and I am always unsure of how to commemorate them, as I lack an halachic obligation to do so. (Furthermore, my paternal grandfather was German, thus diaqualifying El-Male further). What are some typical things done in just such an instance?

Comment: Why is it necessary to observe the Jahrzeit of a grandparent?

Comment: It's not. However, I feel that I should do something, despite lacking an obligation.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Why is it necessary to observe the Jahrzeit of anyone?

Comment: My grandfather (my father's father) passed away on the first day of Pesach.  As both my father and I are first borns, when my father was alive, we would sponsor the breakfast at our shul for the siyum for the first born on the morning before Pesach.  I also usually do the haftorah on the first day of Pesach.

Answer (score 2):

The main things done for a yahrtzeit are:

- Getting Maftir on the Shabbos before
- Getting an Aliya to the torah
- Davening from the Amud
- Learning mishnayos l'ilui nishmas the niftar
- Lighting a yahrtziet candle
- Saying Kaddish
- Going to the kever and reciting certain pirkei Tehilim
- Reciting Kel Maleh Rachamim
- Fasting

Of all the above listed items, the only ones proscribed because of chodesh Nissan is Kel Maleh Rachamim and fasting. ([see Sefer Pnei Baruch for more details](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47632&st=&pgnum=443&hilite=))

Comment: And how many of those for someone who isn't chayav l'aveilut after the petirah?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt These are all observances that are prescribed for children of the niftar. I don't believe there are any specific customs for grandchildren, but none of these can hurt. Again though, none of them are proscribed because of chodesh Nissan except for fasting and Kel Male Rachamim

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Saying Kaddish might be a bit of a problem, but the rest seem totally permissible for anyone.

Comment: @Scimonster The only possible problem that I can think of with saying kaddish is if both the parents of the one saying kaddish are alive, and even there if they give express permission there is no problem. Also, that problem is not germain to Noach mi Frankfurt's question which pertained to chodesh Nissan specifically

Comment: @Scimonster, unless no-one is saying, Kaddish should always be said.